# Is Sublime Text development still going on?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I've been using ST since version 2 and recently I tried contacting its creators yet with no avail. No response via Twitter and Mail. So, I am asking if anyone knows if there's people still working on ST, if there's going to be a new release anytime soon or if ST will stay on Build 3083 of March 26th, 2015 forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's another release channel, called dev build

Currently:

Build 3099

Release Date: 29 January 2016

https://www.sublimetext.com/3dev

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I've been looking for!